# How do I get rid of the website link in BeautifulSoup? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, css-selectors

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I just want to extract the names of the books that are in hyperlink, but I don't know how to get rid of the link itself. Here is my code below.

```
website=requests.get("Books.com")
soup=BeautfiulSoup(website.text, "lxml")


book_arthur=soup.find_all("a", class_="md-crosslink")


#Getting error, TypeError:'ResultSet' object is not callable
for a in book_arthur("md-crosslink> center> a"):
      a.decompose()
```

This is what I get without trying to decompose.

```
"[<a class="md-crosslink" data-show-preview="true" href="books.com/book/harrypotter">Harry Potter</a>,
<a class="md-crosslink" data-show-preview="true" href="books.com/book/captain-underpants1">Captain Underpants1</a>,"
```

What I just want from decomposing:
Harry Potter
Captain Underpants

If anyone can help me learn how to do this, it would mean so much to me. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_all()` returns a list of results.  (Well, technically it's a `ResultSet`, not a list.)  You need to iterate over this list and process each result individually:

```
results = soup.find_all("a", class_="md-crosslink")
for book_arthur in results:
    for a in book_arthur("md-crosslink> center> a"):
```

Comment: Uhh that didn't work either. Also, I realize I didn't give you guys my results which I just changed to show you. If you can please take a look at it again.

Comment: @MaskShadow Saying "that didn't work" does not describe the problem at all...

Comment: I solved it going off your answer. Basically I needed to create an empty list=[ ] then after the first for loop, empty list.append(books.text). This somehow got rid of the a tag and website while giving me a list of the books onto the empty list.